# confusion about the result of "which conda" in zsh

Tags: zsh

When I input this command in zsh:

```
which conda
```

It returns

```
conda () {
        \local cmd="${1-__missing__}"
        case "$cmd" in
                (activate | deactivate) __conda_activate "$@" ;;
                (install | update | upgrade | remove | uninstall) __conda_exe "$@" || \return
                        __conda_reactivate ;;
                (*) __conda_exe "$@" ;;
        esac
}
```

But I hope it returns the absolute path as it behaves in bash.

When I input:

```
type conda
```

It returns

```
conda is a shell function from /Users/qxchen/.zshrc
```

Actually, there is no function in `.zshrc` named by `conda`

I delete the script in `.zshrc` which is made by "conda init zsh", and then I add the absolute path of `miniconda/bin` to `PATH`.

But in bash, "which conda" returns the absolute path of "conda".

```
/Users/ABC/miniforge3/condabin/conda
```

And the result of "type conda":

```
conda is a function
conda () 
{ 
    \local cmd="${1-__missing__}";
    case "$cmd" in 
        activate | deactivate)
            __conda_activate "$@"
        ;;
        install | update | upgrade | remove | uninstall)
            __conda_exe "$@" || \return;
            __conda_reactivate
        ;;
        *)
            __conda_exe "$@"
        ;;
    esac
}
```

I want zsh to behave like bash at this point, aka "which conda" should return the path of `conda`, and "type conda" should return its real type.

What should I do?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: `conda` actually *is* something different. Just like `kill` can be a program, a function or just an alias, that all depends on your setup. Also, "from ..." doesn't mean exactly in "...", it could as well be in a piece of code imported from there. In any case, provide a [mcve], then you will be clear about what is happening here. For a start, create a new user to get a pristine state.